# Swift xcode auto layout even spacing between labels

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout, constraints

I have 3 labels which all have child label centered under them.

I have a center label which is positioned in the center. Next to it I want to place two labels and give them both a even spacing between the center label and the screen edge. Like in css "margin-right/left: auto;"

Is this possible to do with autolayout / constraints? I want them spacing to be even in 3 different screens.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following in the storyboard?

- Position "Center Label" in the horizontal center using the blue grid
  helper lines.
- Control drag from the leftmost "Label" to "Center Label" and then
  choosing "equal width" and repeat this by control dragging from
  "Center Label" to rightmost "Label".
- Repeat same procedure with the three "Long label".

The result would look like this:

[image: Storyboard]

The constraints look as follows:

- for Wide Label

[image: Constraints Wide Label]

- for Label

[image: Constraints Label]

- for Very Wide Label

[image: Constraints Very Wide Label]

Answer (score 1):

Here steps for you

1. add top and width/height constraint for your center label

[image]

2. align horisontally

[image]

3. add left, top, heigth, right constraints for side lables

[image]

Repeat the same action for right label

Hope this helps